# Apps don't run due to 'qmlscene: could not fins a Qt installation of ''' error

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I followed this [Link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/03/how-to-play-with-ubuntu-touch-apps-in-ubuntu-12-10) to install the ubuntu touch core apps on my computer running 13.04. But when I run the command `ubuntu-calculator-app` I get the error `qmlscene: could not fins a Qt installation of ''`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the Ubuntu Toolkit components. Follow the steps here to "Get the Ubuntu SDK Preview". http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/