# How to fix the error qmlscene: could not find a Qt installation of '' in Ubuntu Unity 22.10?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, application-development, 22.10, qml

I compiled [this](https://github.com/MaxPerl/SimplePiano) app made for Ubuntu Touch in Ubuntu Unity 22.10.

The app can be run with `qmlscene %U /path/to/qml/Main.qml`.

When I run `qmlscene`, I get the error

```
qmlscene: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

I installed the packages `qtbase5-dev qtchooser qt5-qmake qtbase5-dev-tools` following this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67415291) answer, but I still get the same error.

[This](https://askubuntu.com/q/308341/124466) question did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to run **qmlscene** on a new Ubuntu 22.04 jammy system recently.

First I ran into this error:

```
qmlscene: could not find a Qt installation of ''
```

Then after some series of further apt commands, I eliminated that error but landed on an even longer one:

```
plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Controls": Cannot protect module QtQuick.Controls 2 as it was never registered
```

The apt packages that I had installed were:

```
qtbase5-dev
qtchooser
qt5-qmake
qtbase5-dev-tools
qtcreator
```

When I used `which` to query where qmlscene was being launched from, I saw that it was a symlink to the qtchooser utility:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/qmlscene
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Mar 22  2020 /usr/bin/qmlscene -> qtchooser
```

Ultimately, I found a solution that is working for me (on Ubuntu 22.04 jammy, as I mentioned).

I had to edit `/usr/share/qtchooser/qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf` so that qtchooser would select Qt5 binaries from a special install directory of my own creation.

I installed Qt5 into my own chosen directory, using the unofficial installer AQT. https://github.com/miurahr/aqtinstall

Here is my AQT invocation:

```
python3 -m aqt install-qt --base http://ftp.fau.de/qtproject --outputdir /opt/repositories/Qt_desktop linux desktop 5.15.0 --archives icu qtbase qtconnectivity qtdeclarative qtgraphicaleffects qtimageformats qtquickcontrols qtquickcontrols2 qtsvg qttools
```

(I also have scripted it here: https://github.com/219-design/qt-qml-project-template-with-ci/blob/master/tools/ci/get_qt_libs.sh )

Here is the new content of `/usr/share/qtchooser/qt5-x86_64-linux-gnu.conf`:

```
/opt/repositories/Qt_desktop/5.15.0/gcc_64/bin
/opt/repositories/Qt_desktop/5.15.0/gcc_64/lib
#/usr/lib/qt5/bin
#/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```